# Dompdf code shows blank PDF, after upgrading from PHP 7.1 to 7.4

Tags: php, upgrade, dompdf, php-7.4

So code worked and displayed DB data in PDF fine, on PHP 7.1

Upgraded to 7.4 and there were issues due to name changes in the Dompdf library.

```
load_html() became loadHtml() 
set_paper() became SetPaper()
```

once I updated Dompdf to it's latest version, the errors stopped and the pdf downloaded as normally, but contents was just a white blank page now.

Anyone ran across this during upgrading Dompdf code to PHP 7.4? and what was the issue?

The only thing I can think of is that the updated DomPDF library, I just got the latest from its GitHub, may have some dependencies I don't have, but Im not sure how to add those. Its not clear on their GitHub page how to do that. They show a Git way and a Composer way, I don't know how to use those ways really. And they show a manual way , which appears to just download code from their Git manually, which is what I did and I assume I have all the library dependencies they need, am I correct in this?

**No errors in PHP log.**
Any help appreciated.

**Here is code that produces blank PDF, now. didn't for PHP 7.1**

```
<?php

require_once 'dompdf/autoload.inc.php';


$currentPage = $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM `members` where `active` = 1 order by lastname asc ";
$results = $pdo->query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
$rows = $results->fetchAll();
// console_log($rows);
$count = $results->fetchColumn();

// use mysql dresults to generate html to convert.
$html = '<html><header>';
$html .= '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Tangerine:bold">';
$html .= '<link href="css/pdf.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">';
$html .= '<body>';
//echo $html;
// $html .= '<p>test</p>';
//start a loop
$html .= '<h1 Report</h1>';
$html .= '<h2>'.$count.' Members</h2>';
$html .= '<p>Report dated: '.date("F j, Y, g:i a").'</p>'; 
$html .= '<hr>';
foreach ($rows as $r2 )  {  

  $html .= '<span class="volunteers"><strong>'.$r2["lastname"].', '.$r2["firstname"]. '</strong>:&nbsp;&nbsp;  '.$r2["address"].
     ',  '.$r2["phone"]. ',  '.$r2["email"].'.</span><br>';  

} //end while
$html .='<h3>--------------------End of Report--------------------</h3>';
$html .='</body></html>';
              


//$dompdf = new DOMPDF();

use Dompdf\Dompdf;
use Dompdf\Options;

$options = new Options();
$options->set('defaultFont', 'Courier');

// instantiate and use the dompdf class
$dompdf = new Dompdf($options);
$dompdf->loadHtml($html);
$dompdf->setPaper('A4', 'landscape');
$dompdf->render();
$dompdf->stream("mvyc-all-active-members-report.pdf");
?>
```

**UPDATE**

The issue appears to be in the html code as presented. Because if I replace the html generation part with a simple:

```
$dompdf->loadHtml('<h1> The Report</h1>');
```

The PDF is not blank and contains the html. So somewhere the new upgraded DomPDF does not like the way im presenting the HTML to it in $html variable. Any idea are appreciated. MaYBE

obs_clean; or something to purge html?

Answer (score 0):

It seems the solution was that:

My HTML code was indeed not PERFECT HTML format. Older versions of the DomPDF library were forgiving to my imperfect HTML, but the latest versions are NOT. After reviewing my HTRML closely I found that I opened a  tag but had NO closing  tag and once I corrected this, the PDF displayed the data as intended. So, yeah, with DOMPDF, a blank PDF means your HTML is not up to specs, and you should review it thoroughly.